# Need to divide every 12 integers in a text file by 12 to simulate months in a year

Tags: python

**I am creating a program that divides every 12 integers in a text file to simulate getting the average rain fall for a year, to give an example, if there are 15 integers on separate lines, it will take the first 12 and divide the total by 12 to get the average for the year, and then it will separate the last three and make it into a new year, i am thinking about making an else statement that resets the month counter to 0 but I could use some advice.**

```
def main():
    rain_per_month = open('RainperMonth.txt', 'r')
#this is to open the text file with the numbers

    months = 0
#start the accumulator to keep track of the total amount of months
    rainfall = 0
#this is to keep track of the total amount of rainfall
    years = 0
    for line in rain_per_month:
#this is a loop that will go line by line and begin to modify the variables
        months += 1
#this is increasing the number of months according to the number of lines
#for example if there are 15 lines it will keep count of those 15 lines as seperate months
        rainfall = int(line) + rainfall
#this will convert the numbers on the line from being a symbol for 4 to really being the number 4 and 
adding it to the total amount of rainfall
    if months % 12 == 0:
        avg_rain = rainfall / months
        
#Where I am going to seperate the different months and calculate the total for eac
    
    print(avg_rain)
#where the caculations for the rain will be made
main()
```

Comment: Are the integers present in separate lines?

Comment: What if there are 25 integers? How the logic supposed to work? Also, the if condition need to be inside the for loop based on the problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Just modified your logic a bit.
Steps ->

1. Load the file content into a list.
2. Take the subset of the list of length =12(see steps count in for loop)
3. Calculate average.
4. Here, enumerate will auto-increment year.

```
def main():
    with open('RainperMonth.txt', 'r') as f:
        content = f.read().splitlines()
    for years, i in enumerate(range(0, len(content), 12), start=1):
        rain_per_month = content[i:i+12]
        # print(rain_per_month)
        rainfall = 0
        for months, line in enumerate(rain_per_month, start=1):
            rainfall = int(line) + rainfall
        avg_rain = rainfall / len(rain_per_month)
        print(f'avg_rain = {avg_rain} for year = {years}')

main()
```